# Why is my Minecraft server using so much RAM?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

My Minecraft server is always using almost full RAM, while there are only about 10 people online on the server.
This is the command line I used:

`java -Xms128M -Xmx10G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=40 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=4 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=90 -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:SurvivorRatio=32 -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -Dusing.aikars.flags=https://mcflags.emc.gs -Daikars.new.flags=true -jar server.jar nogui`

Comment: What kind of system do you have?

Comment: We have quite a few questions like this one: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144792/why-is-my-servers-memory-usage-so-high-with-just-5-players-online https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/381844/why-is-my-minecraft-server-always-using-100-of-available-ram https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142226/minecraft-map-using-excessive-amount-of-ram